# Excel: Baloon Chart: Automated lines between data points with text

Tags: excel, charts, timeline, bubble-chart

If I have multiple data points on a bubble graph. Is there any way to get a line drawn between data-point-pairs, with a text box?
 - This will probably need some coding skill.

Here is a representation of what I am looking for, however the lines between data-point-pairs, with a text box was manually drawn.

[image]
Please help!

Answer (score 0):

**Line:**

Right-click one of the data-points and "add trend-line" (linear). Right-click to format the trend-line and select arrows in begin/end arrow type

**Text:**

There a various ways of doing this, a simple solution: Go to Chart Tools->Format->Insert shape and type "= Cell with text+value to be displayed" in the formula bar when editing the text-box. People can join in as there may be a more sleek way of creating data-labels for a trend line.

**Save it:**

Right-click the chart and "Save as template" for future use.

Comment: Thanks, but like I mentioned about "large amounts of data", manually adding a trend-line will not be suitable, as there will be many pairs of data points, with many connecting lines needed between them, with many labels needed above those lines. Getting a solution between 2 data points, should yield a solution for many. Please help.

Comment: How much of this have you already completed and is working? Post that code so that we can build from there instead of from scratch. See [.trendlines.add method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.trendlines.add) to get started.

Comment: I have completed none yet, so still at scratch, as I am still searching for a solution. I know how to this with Matlab but not yet in excel. The trend line option will only be a representation of the trend for many data points. I need a line between every 2 data points.

Comment: I would suggest that you update the question/picture to what you actually want, not a simplified graph.

Comment: Here it is, crystal?